# Where get the WSDL for standards methods

Tags: apex, api, soap-api, soap, wsdl

I would like to know where I can get the WSDL for standards methods for one object.

I mean, I would like to know how I can get the WSDL for the standards methods for the order object (CRUD).

If I click on the "Generate WSDL" button on the Apex classes page, I get all methods of all the organization.

Same thing if I click on the "Generate WSDL" button on a apex web service page, I think I get all organization (21k+ lines).

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://docs):

> **Choosing a WSDL**
>
> There are two Lightning Platform Web services for which you can obtain WSDL files for API access:
>
> **Lightning Platform Enterprise WSDL**—This API is for most enterprise users who are developing client applications for their organization.
>
> **Lightning Platform Partner WSDL**—This API is for Salesforce partners who are developing client applications for multiple
>   organizations. As a loosely-typed representation of the Salesforce
>   object model, the partner WSDL can be used to access data within any
>   organization.

Either one of these two WSDLs will include methods for all standard objects. SF does not provide an out of the box facility for "reducing" the WSDL to just the object you need.