# Authentication that does not use oAuth

Tags: rest-api, oauth2, apexrest

Is it possible to retrieve client id & secret without Connected App creating?
As well - is it possible to use rest only with username, password and tocken?

Comment: Definitely doable: I found the answer here:
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/56342/rest-api-without-connected-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client id and client secret are "properties" of the connected app. Thus, it's not possible to retrieve them or have them without creating a connected app.

You can authenticate without a connected app but it won't be a RESTful call. You'll have to use [SOAP `login()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_login.htm). It accepts username/password (which may require inclusion of a security token) and produces a session ID. You can then use this session ID as a bearer token to call REST or other APIs.

Comment: Could you please explain me how can I consume this SOAP directly from Postman?

Comment: @pincet Grab a [Partner WSDL](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/278560/where-get-the-wsdl-for-standards-methods/) and follow a Postman [tutorial](https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/making-soap-requests/). Alternatively, you can try [SoapUI](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/api_basics/api_basics_soap)